# How to get tab completion when using curly braces in Bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I want to have tab completion when using curly braces in a command in bash.

For example:

```
cp ~/html/{foo bar.txt whatever} /var/www/html/
```

I want the tab completion for the files stated in the curly braces

Comment: I don't know if bash can do that. Zsh does (it just works), you might consider switching.

Comment: Your example command should have commas in it, right? In order to be valid [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), as in: `cp ~/html/{foo,bar.txt,whatever} /var/www/html/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to interpret the question: you want the completion while you are typing the names before the closing `}` (in effect performing completion of files in another directory); or, you want the completion to expand and substitute the (valid) names after the closing `}`. `{ }` expansion expands all the options, unlike globbing which expands *existing* file names, though using "," rather than space.

With bash, the expected way to use `{}` to create a list of words is:

```
cp ~/html/{foo,bar.txt,whatever}  ...
```

There are two options: associating a readline key binding with a shell function, or programmable completion.

The readline approach gives you a free hand to completely rewrite the current command, but the problem is that it doesn't tokenise the current command line, so you have a non-trivial parsing problem.

Programmable completion *does* tokenise the command line, but you can only modify/replace the current word, which means you can't (easily) preserve the `path/{` prefix during editing.

The only related native bash capability is the `readline` function `shell-expand-line` for bash purports to do "all of the shell word expansions", this is bound by default to `\M-\C-e` (Esc `\C-e`). One might reasonably expect this expansion to be all of the seven types of expansion indicated in the man page (bash-4.3):

> ```
> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into
> words.   There are seven kinds of expansion performed: brace expansion,
> tilde expansion, parameter and variable  expansion,  command  substitu‐
> tion, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion.
> ```

You can experiment with by typing (without hitting Return)

```
echo {1..2} ~root $0 $LANG `echo foo` $((1+2) "a b" /etc/p[aeiou]*
```

And then <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> (or <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> if you are using a Meta-impaired keyboard).

Neither the first nor last (brace and path) expansions work for me, so the documentation and implementation don't quite match IMHO.

What follows is a work-around, rather than complete solution using tab for expansion. You need to make sure to use the correct syntax for brace expansion though, specifically with a comma to separate the items, not a space.

```
function _expand() {
   [[ -z "${READLINE_LINE}" ]] && return
   eval local aa=( ${READLINE_LINE} )       # not-quoted, eval needed
   [[ ${#aa} -eq 0 ]] && return             # parse problem
   printf -v READLINE_LINE "%s " "${aa[@]}"
   READLINE_POINT=${#READLINE_LINE}         # eol, predictable at least
}

bind -x '"\C-_":_expand'
```

This binds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> to a bash function which uses `eval` to populate an array, causing all the normal expansions (as above, and not including history) to occur, and then rebuilds the command line.

Start typing, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> when you want something expanded, and <kbd>Return</kbd> as normal when ready.

This is more powerful than tab, but less precise in that it expands the complete input line.  There are a few cases where this won't expand as hoped, specifically where various shell metacharacters confuse the simple `eval` logic.

Rather than over-engineer a bash solution, Gille's suggestion of `zsh` is worth a look.

Comment: Your `eval` is at risk of executing arbitrary code - `$READLINE_LINE` need only contain a `)` and your user is in serious trouble. You could do a much safer job of this with `$IFS` probably.

Comment: @mikeserv that's absolutely correct, `eval` is not something to invoke lightly (or possibly at all). I can't think of a scenario where the input isn't something the user typed/pasted into the shell command line however. Suggestions for a safer alternative way to expand the troublesome `{}` welcome...

Comment: mr. spuratic - `eval` can be safely invoked given parameter validation. And nevermind the IFS thing - because you're already using it actually - and globbing as well. So the `)` statement I made before was incorrect - your `$READLINE_LINE` need not contain a `)` to offer serious risk to operational security - it need only contain a glob that matches a filename containing a `)`, in fact. That or any backquotes or `$(...)` or any number of other shell tokens that could result in code execution.

Answer (score 2):

In a Ubuntu (16.04) terminal you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> and then <kbd>{</kbd> and it autocompletes the curly brackets with the files in the directory. It uses commas instead of spaces to separate the files. For example, a directory containing these files:

`file.cpp file.h file.i file.py file_wrap.cxx`

... would auto complete to this:

`$ cp file{.{cpp,h,i,py},_wrap.cxx}`

Comment: Hah. I did this by accident one time and was like "WTF just happened??"

Comment: Yep, I think that's kind of how I found about it too ... plus a few hours afterwards web searching for it. Perhaps that's how I end up writing this answer.

Comment: The code that implements this makes for some C programming fun: https://opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-86.1/bash-3.2/bracecomp.c.auto.html

Answer (score 0):

Braces (which, by definition, are "curly") in this context refer to a list of fragments of text, separated by commas. While it's most often used for file names, it gets expanded **before** file name expansions are handled. Therefore, there is no definitive expansion capability, because `bash` cannot know if you're actually typing a file name or not.

Answer (score 0):

From `man bash`:

```
COMP_WORDBREAKS
       The  set  of  characters  that  the readline
       library treats as word separators when  per‐
       forming word completion.  If COMP_WORDBREAKS
       is unset, it loses its  special  properties,
       even if it is subsequently reset.
```

I thought that was interesting, so I did:

```
printf %q\\n "${COMP_WORDBREAKS}"
```

...to have a look at its default value. This got me:

```
$' \t\n"\'@><=;|&(:'
```

So I figured, why not...?

```
$ COMP_WORDBREAKS="{}$COMP_WORDBREAKS"
$ {/<TAB><TAB>
```

...where the `<TAB>` part represents my actually pressing the `<TAB>` key, and I saw:

```
$ {/
bin/      esp/      lib/      opt/      run/      sys/      usr/      
boot/     etc/      lib64/    proc/     sbin/     testuser/ var/      
dev/      home/     mnt/      root/     srv/      tmp/
```

So that was neat. I then did:

```
$ COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS#??}
$ {/<TAB><TAB>
```

...and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I provide diagnostics tool which enables the OP to directly observe the behavior of line completion after tab, and for comparison, the behavior of parsing after return.  After observation and analysis, we may conclude that while writing a line completion function to complete curly brackets function might be possible - it would be pointless due to bash's limitation of suppressing any further line completion functionality after the curly brackets.

The following bash script enables the diagnostics:

```
#!/bin/bash

confirm_args(){
    logger -t "confirm_args" -- "#=${#}"
    for index in `seq 0 ${#}` ; do
        eval item=\$$index
        logger -t "confirm_args" -- "[$index] ${item}"
    done    
}

_foo_completion(){
    logger -t "_foo_completion" -- "COMP_CWORD=${COMP_CWORD}" 
    logger -t "_foo_completion" -- "#COMP_WORDS=${#COMP_WORDS[@]}"
    for index in `seq 0 $((${#COMP_WORDS[@]}-1))` ; do
        logger -t "_foo_completion" -- "[$index] ${COMP_WORDS[$index]}"
    done
}
declare -f _foo_completion
complete -F _foo_completion "foo"
alias foo=confirm_args
```

I have made it available as a gist [`foo-completion.sh`](https://gist.github.com/craigphicks/af418e9eb57a493276da60c9e1905044).

Copy and paste it into a file `/tmp/foo-completion.sh`.

Create two dummy files

```
touch /tmp/a.{1,2}
```

In order for the diagnostics to function correctly, `logger` must write to the system log.  Then the OP will be able to view the diagnostic output by following the system log file.  If the OP is running `systemd` it can viewed by opening a new window and entering

```
sudo journalctl -f
```

Activate the line completion and diagnostic output:

```
source /tmp/foo-completion.sh
```

Note that the `_foo_completion` does NOT perform any completion, thus no candidates are return to the user.  All it does is show what data is passed to the line completion function.

Test some inputs and observe the outputs:

**INPUT 1**

```
foo a.*[SPACE][TAB]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Jul 23 12:10:34 ub18 _foo_completion[17672]: COMP_CWORD=2
Jul 23 12:10:34 ub18 _foo_completion[17673]: #COMP_WORDS=3
Jul 23 12:10:34 ub18 _foo_completion[17675]: [0] foo
Jul 23 12:10:34 ub18 _foo_completion[17676]: [1] /tmp/a.*
Jul 23 12:10:34 ub18 _foo_completion[17677]: [2]
```

**INPUT 2**

```
foo a.*[SPACE][RETURN]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Jul 23 12:19:43 ub18 confirm_args[18487]: #=2
Jul 23 12:19:43 ub18 confirm_args[18489]: [0] bash
Jul 23 12:19:43 ub18 confirm_args[18490]: [1] /tmp/a.1
Jul 23 12:19:43 ub18 confirm_args[18491]: [2] /tmp/a.2
```

**INPUT 3**

```
foo a.{1,2}[SPACE][TAB]
```

**OUTPUT**

*NOTE - no output!*

**INPUT 4**

```
foo a.{1,2}[SPACE][RETURN]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Jul 23 12:28:42 ub18 confirm_args[19098]: #=2
Jul 23 12:28:42 ub18 confirm_args[19100]: [0] bash
Jul 23 12:28:42 ub18 confirm_args[19101]: [1] /tmp/a.1
Jul 23 12:28:42 ub18 confirm_args[19102]: [2] /tmp/a.2
```

### Analysis

In "INPUT 1" the `*` is passed to the line completion function as a literal character '*'. However, in "INPUT 3" the line completion function is not even called.  Apparently the curly brackets cause bash to suppress any further calls to the line completion function.

On the other hand, in the post [RETURN] parsing cases **INPUT 2** and **INPUT 4**, bash expands both cases `a.*` and `a.{1,2}` to the same result.

One more test case:

**INPUT 5**

```
foo a.{[TAB]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Jul 23 12:56:52 ub18 _foo_completion[21059]: COMP_CWORD=1
Jul 23 12:56:52 ub18 _foo_completion[21060]: #COMP_WORDS=2
Jul 23 12:56:52 ub18 _foo_completion[21062]: [0] foo
Jul 23 12:56:52 ub18 _foo_completion[21063]: [1] /tmp/a.{
```

### Analysis

In "INPUT 5", with no space before the tab, bash *DOES* call line completion.  So a line completion could theoretically return a single candidate

```
/tmp/a.{1,2}
```

which should result in auto-completion (although I haven't tested).

The ***problem*** with that would be that ***further*** files could not be added with line completion, because the curly brackets suppress line completion.

Testing with a preexisting line completion function, e.g.,

**INPUT CHECK**

```
ls /tmp/a.{[TAB][TAB][TAB][TAB][TAB][TAB]
```

**OUTPUT**

(nothing)

seems to support the thesis that it's not worth supporting curlies in a line completion function until/unless bash doesn't suppress line completion after curlies.

EDIT:  After playing around with the `[CTRL]{{` method described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527950/247579), I found it complete and was (sometimes) able to be followed by the default completion function to add more files.  However, there was no way to continue with the original `_foo_completion` function after that, which may or may not be a limitation depending on the usage case.